# pandas dataframe merge based on str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe that I would like to merge based on if column value from df2 contains column value from df1. I've been trying to use str.contains and series.isin. But no luck so far. Example below.

df1

```
       Domain              Visits
         aaa                  1 
         bbb                  3
         ddd                  5
```

df2

```
       Domain                Ads
         aaa.com              2 
         bbb                  4
         c.com                3
         e.net                6
```

Merged Dataframe should be like this

mergeDF

```
       Domain              Visits       Ads
         aaa.com              1          2
         bbb                  3          4
         c.com                           3
         ddd                  5          
         e.net                           6
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you double check your output? Shouldn't `dd` have 5 in the visits column, not ads? Also, shouldn't `c.com` have a 3 in the ads, not the visits?

Comment: You are correct, I will fix it. Thank you for catching it.

Comment: What should happen to an element in `df2` that does not contain anything from `df1`? What should if multiple elements in `df2` match a given element in `df1`?

Comment: 1. that element will still exist in mergeDF.  2. Great catch, I haven't really thought about it. But I think if multiple elements match, it should sum up the value of both Visits and Ads.  @fuglede

Answer (score 4):

***Setup***

We can start by creating a new series which is the row each domain in `df2` corresponds to in `df1`, if such a row exists:

```
r = '({})'.format('|'.join(df1.Domain))
merge_df = df2.Domain.str.extract(r, expand=False).fillna(df2.Domain)
```

Our `merge_df` now looks like this:

```
0      aaa
1      bbb
2    c.com
3    e.net
Name: Domain, dtype: object
```

---

Now we merge. We want an outer merge here, merging our first DataFrame on the `Domain` column, and our second DataFrame on our `merge_df` series:

```
df1.merge(df2.drop('Domain', 1), left_on='Domain', right_on=merge_df, how='outer')
```

```
 Domain  Visits  Ads
0    aaa     1.0  2.0
1    bbb     3.0  4.0
2    ddd     5.0  NaN
3  c.com     NaN  3.0
4  e.net     NaN  6.0
```

Since we stored a separate series to merge on, and didn't modify `df2`, we are done after this step, and you have your merged DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Try and preprocess df2, to get domain in the same format as df1:

```
df2['key'] = df2['Domain'].str.extract('(\w+)\.?')

df_out = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Domain', right_on='key', suffixes=('_x',''), how='outer')

df_out['Domain'] = df_out['Domain'].combine_first(df_out['Domain_x'])

df_out = df_out.drop(['Domain_x','key'], axis=1)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   Visits   Domain  Ads
0     1.0  aaa.com  2.0
1     3.0      bbb  4.0
2     5.0      ddd  NaN
3     NaN    c.com  3.0
4     NaN    e.net  6.0
```